# Cannot find symbol error en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy creando una proyecto y me he encontrado con dos errores y no soy capaz de solucionarlos. Para poneros en contexto, la explicación de este proyecto es la siguiente:

Debo crear en un mismo paquete dos clases, "Vehículo" y "Principal".

La clase Vehículo tiene el siguiente código.

```
package com.mycompany.prog03_ejerc1.COCHES;

//Clase vehículo
public class Vehiculo { 
    
    //Declaración de los tipos enum
    public enum enumMarca {Renault, Ford, Mercedes, BMW, Toyota,Kia}
    public enum enumMes {Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre}
    
    //Declaración de atributos
    public String matricula;
    public enumMarca marca;
    public String color;
    public Integer klm;
    public int dia;
    public enumMes mes;
    public int anio;
    
    //Implementación del constructor que inicia el vehículo vacio.
    public Vehiculo() {
        this.matricula = "";
        this.marca = null;
        this.color = "";
        this.klm = 0;
        this.dia = 0;
        this.mes = null;
        this.anio = 0;
    }
    //Declaración de otro constructor que inicia todo los atributos de la clase
    public Vehiculo (String matricula, enumMarca marca, String color, Integer klm, int dia, enumMes mes, int anio) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
        this.klm = klm;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.anio = anio;
    }
    
    //Implementación de métodos que permiten acceder y modificar cada uno de los atributos de las clase.
    
    //Enums
    public enumMarca getMarca () {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(enumMarca marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    
    public enumMes getMes () {
        return mes;
    }
    public void setMes(enumMes mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }
    
    //Atributos
    
    //Matricula
    public String getmatricula () {
        return matricula;
    }
    public void setmatricula (String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    //Color
    public String getcolor () {
        return color;
    }
    public void setcolor (String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    //Kilometros
    public Integer getklm () {
        return klm;
    }
    public void setklm (Integer klm) {
        this.klm = klm;
    }
    //Dia
    public int getdia () {
        return dia;
    }
    public void setdia (int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }
    //Año
    public int getanio () {
        return anio;
    }
    public void setanio (int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }
    
    //Método para devolver una cadena con todos los valores del vehículo y con la fecha en formato largo.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String vehiculo = "";
        vehiculo += "Matricula: " + this.getmatricula() + "\n";
        vehiculo += "Marca: " + this.getMarca().name() + "\n";
        vehiculo += "Color: " + this.getcolor() + "\n";
        vehiculo += "Kilómetros: " + this.getklm() + "\n";
        vehiculo += "Fecha: " + this.getdia() + " de " + this.getMes().name() + " de " + this.getanio() + "\n";
        return vehiculo;
}

}
```

En esta primera clase, no tengo ningún tipo de problemas. Hasta aquí todo bien, mi problema comienza en la clase "Principal", os explico lo que debo hacer en esta clase.

- Instancia un objeto de la clase Vehiculo denominado objVeh1 con el
  constructor vacio.
- Actualiza los atributos para dicho objeto pidiéndolos por teclado y
  utlizando los métodos set para inicializar sus atributos.
- Muestra los datos del vehículo introducido por pantalla, la fecha en
  formato largo, mediante los métodos get declarados.
- Instancia otro objeto de la clase Vehiculo denomiando objVeh2 con el
  segundo constructor directamente sin pedir los datos por teclado.
- Saca por consola los datos de este segundo vehículo con el método
  toString.

Aquí está el código de la clase "Principal" y los errores que no soy capaz de solucionar.

```
package com.mycompany.prog03_ejerc1.COCHES;

import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        Vehiculo objVeh1 = new Vehiculo();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la matrícula del vehículo: ");
        objVeh1.setmatricula(sc.nextLine());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el color del vehículo: ");
        objVeh1.setcolor(sc.nextLine());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese los kilometros del vehículo: ");
        objVeh1.setklm(sc.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el día: ");
        objVeh1.setdia(sc.nextByte());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el mes: ");
        objVeh1.setmes(sc.nextLine());
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el año: ");
        objVeh1.setanio(sc.nextByte());
        
        System.out.println("Matrícula: "+ objVeh1.getmatricula());
        System.out.println("Marca: "+ objVeh1.getMarca());
        System.out.println("Color: " + objVeh1.getcolor());
        System.out.println("Kilómetros: " + objVeh1.getklm());
        System.out.println("Fecha: " + objVeh1.getdia() + " de " + objVeh1.getMes() + " de " + objVeh1.getanio());
        
        Vehiculo objVeh2 = new Vehiculo("2321AMP", marca.BMW,"Rojo",9000,25, mes.Enero,2022);
        
        System.out.println("\nSegundo vehiculo, inicializado con el segundo Vehículo");
        System.out.println(objVeh2.toString());
        
        
    }
}
```

Los errores son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es `setMes` con mayúsculas, no `setmes`.

Comment: Declara los enums en su propio archivo para que puedas acceder a ellos de manera publica. No los coloques ahi mismo dentro de la clase Vehiculo, ya que vas a necesitar una instancia para poder acceder a estos enums. Alternativamente puedes hacerlos estáticos y acceder a ellos usando `Vehiculo.enumMarca.BMW` en lugar de `enumMarca.BMW`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando la clase Vehiculo, el método getMes lleva la M en mayúscula, por lo que getmes no existe. Recuerda que java es sensible a las mayúsculas y minúsculas, debes tener cuidado con eso.

Comment: Hola StevenLz, ya lo probé, al poner  objVeh1.setMes(sc.nextLine()); me sigue dando error y esta vez no es de setMes, sino de sc.nextLine() el error dice lo siguiente: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to enumMes

Comment: @pabl1ku porque a un metodo que recibe un enum no le podes pasar una cadena ;)

Comment: Perdóneme por la pregunta, pero ¿Cómo debería hacerlo entonces? No encuentro manera de solucionar ese error.

Comment: Para que funcione el método setMes debe recibir un tipo de dato enumMes, para eso puedes enviarlo así:        objVeh1.setMes(Vehiculo.enumMes.valueOf(sc.nextLine())); El valueOf nos ayuda a llamar el item del enum, devolviendo el valor primitivo del String. En caso de que el usuario ingrese Enero por línea de comando, lo que se estaría ejecutando con el valueOf sería Vehículo.enumMes.Enero.

Comment: @StevenLz eso no le va a servir porque los enums que declaró dentro de la clase no son estáticos.